# Помогите разобраться с регулярков в JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем у меня есть регулярк она должна очистить все и выдать числа.

```
 function is_phone(phone){
                if( phone.match(/\d{1,}/g)==null){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Вот тут я проверяю

```
if(is_phone(phone)){
            phone.match(/\d{1,}/g).join('');
        }
        else{
            $('#inputregPhone').css('border', 'red 1px solid');
            error=2;
        }
```

по итогу выходит неочищенная строка(( хотелось бы получить строку вот такого типа 3094323453423 а не такого 43(43)1-2-34234

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: _по итогу выходит_ - как ты проверял?

Comment: я записываю все в файл.

Comment: `phone.match(/\d{1,}/g).join('');` ➔ `phone = phone.replace(/\D/g, '');`

Comment: Да да ))) после твоих слов я так и сделал)) все норм стало)) спасибо большое)